# Enabling global hibernate filters in a spring data jpa and spring boot application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I am working on a method of applying row level security to a spring data application transparently. I would like to use hibernate filters to accomplish this, but I am unable to get the aop pointcuts to intercept where spring data opens the session. What is the appropriate pointcut needed or is there a better approach to row level security that I can explore?

Ps: I need the security filtering to occur before the query to not affect paging and sorting of the data returned.

Thanks

Comment: Great solution! If you could add an answer to this question with an example of your interceptor and a small use case I would be much obliged and it would certainly be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32230857/320761

Answer (score 0):

I think the better approach would be to use Spring Security ACL. It's a little bit complex when you implement it for the first time, but it's the right way to do this.

Check out: http://grzegorzborkowski.blogspot.hr/2008/10/spring-security-acl-very-basic-tutorial.html

For database filtering you will have to write Specifications and use them in criteria queries.