# Why createEntityManager is called before my REST controller method

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, entitymanagerfactory

This is more of a Spring JPA (Hibernate) related issue than AspectJ one, I believe.

Spring Boot v2.2.2.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.2.RELEASE, Hibernate v5.4.9.Final, Spring Data Repositories

I am trying to implement Multi-tenancy in my existing single tenant application.

- The tenant is chosen by the users via front-end. The tenant id is
  stored in HttpSession.
- An advice for Rest Controller methods, reads
  the tenant id and keeps it in a ThreadLocal variable.

Now I have to enable a Hibernate Filter using the tenant id. For this, an AspectJ advice for my Repository (interface extends JpaRepository) methods work, but gets executed for each repository method call from Service.

This post is about the following (identical) implementations where the advice for enabling Hibernate Filter is fired before the advice for reading the tenant id from HttpSession. How do I correct the order? The advice for reading the tenant id does not make any repository calls.

- `@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory+.createEntityManager(..))", returning = "entityManager")`
  Ref: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25125 (This thread contains a non-AOP way also - post-processing transactional EntityManager instances - That gets triggered only when the Spring Boot starts)
- `@AfterReturning(pointcut="bean(entityManagerFactory) && execution(* createEntityManager(..))", returning="retVal")`
  Ref: [Access to Session using Spring JPA and Hibernate in order to enable filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228031/access-to-session-using-spring-jpa-and-hibernate-in-order-to-enable-filters/32230857#32230857)

I tried setting the application property spring.jpa.open-in-view=false, but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy

Comment: Could you please point me to the relevant portion. Thanks.