# Add a where condition to all the queries in a Repository in spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I would like to add a set of where conditions to all the custom queries in a repository.

```
public class TransactionEntity {
    
    ...


    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "INPUT_DT")
    Date inputDate;
    
    ...

}
```

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<TransactionEntity, String> {

// Custom queries

}
```

I would like to add fromDate and toDate to every custom query in this repository.

Is there a method to do that.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  You will have to refactor the native/JPQL queries and/or rename the factory methods.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the quick reply. I am not aware of the Factory methods. Can you give any references to the factory methods.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How to modify the factory methods

Comment: i think hibernate @Filter can help you.see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32230857/10622099